# Proper way to embed EXTJS in html

Tags: element, extjs

What is the recommended way to stick Extjs elements in your html?

At the moment I have

```
<div><script type='text/javascript'>
    Ext.onReady(function(){
         new Ext.grid.Panel({params...}).show();
    })
</script></div>
```

But this feels very awkward ( Embedding script tags all over the place rankles my soul )

Components have a renderTo, but if the html element doesn't exist, - I think? ( not too sure about that ) - that the component still gets created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on what you want to do, check out the learning centre on Sencha:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/

http://www.sencha.com/learn/components/

Usually you use a complete layout system, though if you want to attach to an existing element, such as a `div` you'll need something like renderTo.

Comment: Catch is that the viewport doesn't work well if you want to have normal html all over the place ( or atleast I ran into problems when trying to play with it ). And the renderTo is painful in respect to knowing what elements are on the page currently

Comment: Yes, the Viewport consumes the entire body.